# Saving contact to sim card programmatically in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

Can we save contact to sim card programmatically in iOS7. i Google it a lot but didn't find any topic.

Comment: Not possible, Check : https://discussions.apple.com/message/22396506#22396506

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this, at least a normal way that won't get your app rejected. Why do you want to do this? Contact lists on newer devices are never saved on sim cards anymore generally, and instead transferred using web services (such as iCloud and Google).

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that . AddressBook Api is for accessing (read/write) the contacts which stored in iPhone . There is no way to access the sim contacts at least by using the public APIs.

ref :
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/47463-get-contacts-from-sim-card.html

Answer (score 2):

No way to do this,in both code and in physical device.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/22396506#22396506

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The closest you will get to that is using the Address book framework. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744