# Save a contact directly into sim in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Did a lot of research and I found This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211250/saving-contact-to-sim-card-programmatically-in-ios7) but that was 5 years ago. Are there any updates about this issue? I read all the threads but they were more then 4 years old.

**Is there an api available to save contact directly into sim for iPhone?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: on iOS (thank God) is never allowed to access HW.

So You can only use the Apple way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this using following framework in iOS 9 and later

- Contacts
- ContactsUI

Before iOS 9 you will have to use below framework

- AddressBook
- AddressBookUI

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625597/730807)

Comment: its for phonebook.